# Take someone's picture twice in the same photo

Tags: camera

There is an interesting feature in the camera of Samsung Galaxy S phones, called "Add me". Using this, one can take a photo of a person sitting in two postures in the same frame. A normal photo is taken, the person in the photo can change his posture, and again when clicked, the new posture along with the original is taken in the same picture creating a double/twin effect.

Is there any way to do this on other Android devices?

Comment: Fast forward to 2022, [searching for "twin camera" on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=twin%20camera&c=apps) may return quite a few apps.

Answer (score 0):

Even if not exactly the same thing, hearing your description makes me instantly think about Cinemagram, an iPhone app that should be [ported](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/04/10/cinemagram-developer-confirms-android-version-in-the-works-awesome-gifs-coming-your-way/) to Android really soon.

In a nutshell, the application grabs a little video of the chosen subject and then gives the possibility to "animate" a portion of a selected frame. The effect can be both [amazing](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3743701) or [chilling](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3725978), depending on the subject and the skill of the operator.

Here are a few more successfull shots, both wonderful ([Rain](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3724457), [Flag](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3740616)) or, more likely, gruesome ([Eye](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3746554), [Snake](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3744417), [Mom](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3738743), [A bong aint wrong (LOL)](http://cinemagr.am/showSingle/3744614)).

This is surely a nice app to have on the phone, and if you are a Harry Potter enthusiast you could also try to make a newspaper out of it :)